# Get an item's id from an array and remove it from the array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

So I need to get an item's position in an array and also remove it from the array.

```
names = {"bob", "jeff", "harry", "carl"}
```

I would ask for "jeff" for example and it would output 1.

I am then going to be using the item's position to remove the same position in another array. This is for a sorting algorithm that I need to code (without Array.Sort(names)  ) so if there is a better way to do this I would appreciate it.

Comment: You should read the documentation, [Array.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) can easely give out the index. You can't "remove" an item from an array, that's the idea behind arrays... You'll have to use something else like a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: There are all sorts of algorithms - quick sort, bubble sort etc.  Unless you are supposed to wing it, you might search for the steps for one of those at least as a starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "remove" from an Array, but it's not what I would call efficient. You have to resize it with `Array.Resize`, which I believe in the background just recreates it.

```
Dim arrNames As String() = {"bob", "jeff", "harry", "carl"}
Dim sNameToSearchFor As String = "jeff"

For i As Integer = 0 To arrNames.Count - 1
    'Make sure you're not trying to set the last value in the array to itself
    If i <> arrNames.Count - 1 Then
        arrNames(i) = arrNames(arrNames.Count - 1)
    End If

    'Resize the array by removing one and then exit the for loop
    Array.Resize(arrNames, arrNames.Count - 1)
    Exit For
Next
```

Like I said, it's not ideal, but it works.

---

As an alternative, which might do the same as the above in the background...

```
Dim arrNames As String() = {"bob", "jeff", "harry", "carl"}
Dim sNameToSearchFor As String = "jeff"
Dim nIndex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(arrNames, sNameToSearchFor)

'If it's -1 then it didn't find the object in the array
If nIndex <> -1 Then
    'Check to see if it's at the end of the array
    If nIndex <> arrNames.Count - 1 Then
        arrNames(nIndex) = arrNames(arrNames.Count - 1)
    End If

    Array.Resize(arrNames, arrNames.Count - 1)
End If
```